# How to harden elementary OS

Tags: security

I use Elementary OS. How can I secure it? I am not a advanced linux user, but in the past 8 months I have gotten comfortable with using terminal.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I make sure I update regularly, I don't install to many strange ppa's, made sure it asks for a password after the screen turns off because of inactivity etc.